# How to access container api via Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, containers

I need to host api service in Azure App Service.

1. I created application which can be called by 3000 port.
2. Create a docker image.
3. Upload it to Azure Container Registry.
4. Crated App Service with link to proper container.

But how can I call it and see my "Hello world"? In overview section I see "URL", but when I call it, I have -  "*If you are the application administrator, you can access the link bla bla*"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you expose port 3000 using an Azure Web App Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693878/how-do-you-expose-port-3000-using-an-azure-web-app-container)

Comment: Set WEBSITES_PORT to 3000