# How to specify -p 5000:5000 in Dockerfile or Docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have a flask application that I've built and running it outside of docker has been fine. I am now attempting to deploy to Azure Web.

I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-buster

EXPOSE 5000
COPY requirements.txt .

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .


# gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn-cfg.py", "run:app"]
```

and this docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  appseed-app:
    container_name: appseed_app
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    networks:
      - db_network
      - web_network
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - web_network
    depends_on: 
      - appseed-app
networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
  web_network:
    driver: bridge
```

`docker run -i -t -p 5000:5000 <my-image> /bin/bash` runs fine and I can connect to my container from http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html

When I deploy to Azure Web, I think that it's running, but I'm getting a timeout error. I believe it's working with the docker run command because I am specifying port forwarding 5000:5000, but I apparently am not doing that in my Dockerfile, but I'm not sure what I have  to change

Also, as a reference, I've included `gunicorn-cfg.py`

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (c) 2019 - present AppSeed.us
"""

bind = '0.0.0.0:5000'
workers = 1
accesslog = '-'
loglevel = 'debug'
capture_output = True
enable_stdio_inheritance = True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you expose port 3000 using an Azure Web App Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693878/how-do-you-expose-port-3000-using-an-azure-web-app-container)

Comment: I saw that thread earlier. I EXPOSE 5000 in the Dockerfile, but that wasn't the issue

Comment: I also should specify that setting WEBSITES_PORT to 5000 didn't resolve this

Answer (score 0):

> I apparently am not doing that in my Dockerfile, but I'm not sure what I have to change

Bind the application inside a Docker container to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 in order to allow the docker to allow the access.

**Dockerfile:**

```yaml
# Use the official Python image as the base image
FROM python:3.9-buster

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PORT 5000

# Create and set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the entire application code into the container
COPY . .

# Expose the port your application will run on
EXPOSE $PORT

# Use Gunicorn as the entry point to run the Flask application
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:$PORT", "run:app"]
```

- Use `"gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:$PORT", "run:app"` in the `CMD` to bind Gunicorn to the specified port.

> I also should specify that setting WEBSITES_PORT to 5000 didn't resolve this

Azure Web App for Containers primarily expects applications to listen on port 80 (HTTP) by default.

- Setting `WEBSITES_PORT` to 5000 might not have the desired effect of making your Flask application listen on port 5000, and it could lead to issues.

With these above changes, Flask application Docker container should run on port 80, which aligns with the default port expected by Azure Web App for Containers.